# What is the difference between declaring a variable using Lambda expression and using = operator

Tags: c#

I have a very basic question, what's the difference declaring a variable using Lamda and using `=` operator.

```
  public static string ID => "RETAILER_ID";
  public static string ID = "RETAILER_ID";
```

I am sure someone would have asked this in SO, but I could not find it.

Comment: One is an [expression body member](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/expression-bodied-members), the other is just a variable.

Comment: I am a beginner, can you kindly elaborate, when to use one over other.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first example and the second example are actually quite different.

In the first case, `public static string ID => "RETAILER_ID";` represents a static expression-bodied read-only auto-property.

The second case, `public static string ID = "RETAILER_ID";` is a static field, and as such the value is mutable.

Given the following class, Foo, we can show some of the differences between the two, and I'll add in read-only auto properties as well.

```
public class Foo {
    public static string ExpressionBody => "ExpressionBody";
    public static string StaticField = "StaticField";
    public static string ReadOnlyProperty {get;} = "ReadOnlyProperty";
}
```

Any time you reference `Foo.ExpressionBody`, the expression is going to be evaluated. When this is just returning a constant value this won't be noticeable, but if you're instead using the result of a function, the value returned may be different each time. This is in contrast with the `ReadOnlyProperty`, which will only set the value once. With static values, this will be be done at some point before the type is used or it's static constructor is called. With an instance property, it will be done at the time of object construction.

`StaticField`, on the other hand, is just that. A static field. It is initialized sometime before it is used, and sometime before the static constructor is called, and it's value is not guaranteed to stay the same. ie, `Foo.StaticField = "NewValue!"` is perfectly valid, and will change the value. This should typically be avoided, as it represents global state and can lead to difficult-to-reason code.

`Foo.ExpressionBody` and `Foo.ReadOnlyProperty` cannot be assigned to, however. `ReadOnlyProperty` will always be the value initially assigned to it. `ExpressionBody` will always return the result of the expression. In this case, it's the constant "ExpressionBody", but it could just as easily be `DateTime.Now.ToString()`, which would lead to a different value each time you use `Foo.ExpressionBody`.

Comment: If I strictly talk about the example I have given, in my example, if I replace the former code with this line `public static readonly string ID = "RETAILER_ID"`, it will same as Lamda right. (Again strictly as per my example)

Comment: Thank you so much for such an explanation. :)

Comment: @Unbreakable It may return the same value, and it may not be mutable, but that's where the similarities will cease. The lambda expression evaluating every time you call it can be a subtle, but potentially humongous difference, depending on how the result is derived.

Answer (score 4):

```
public string ID_Property => foo();
public string IF_Field = foo();
```

| `ID_Property` | `ID_Field` |
| --- | --- |
| is a property | is a field |
| will evaluate `foo` each time it is read | the assignment (and evaluation of `foo`) happens just one |
| cannot be assigned to | can be assigned to |
| it can be part of an interface | cannot be part of an interface |

Answer (score 1):

The former is an [expression bodied member](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/expression-bodied-members). It's a function that (in this case) takes no inputs and returns a string result. In this case, it maps a read-only property (just a `get`, no `set`), in the same way that property `get` and `set` blocks are actually functions. Pay special attention to the Property Get Statements section of that documentation link.

The latter is a class field (just a normal string member).